# bootstrap defining space between the divs without leaving the place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a card with html, css and bootstrap and I'm using the bootstrap class col to define the columns. My problem is when separating the divs, how is it possible to define 3 divs with col 4 and get a space between them without leaving the place? when I give a style of margin-left: 5px; for example, the third div goes to the bottom line

[image]

Comment: Your current `code`, as well as your Bootstrap version, is missing in your question.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: if you give 3 divs the col4 tag its the max of the width so you need to make them col3 and then it should work

Comment: I use version 3.3.7, my question is how to give a space horizontally between these divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
.card {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: this causes the 3 div to go to the next line and not all align horizontally.

Comment: @Bruno It's working for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/HHUaUaoWYw2A6N4Opktg?p=preview Any additional CSS that rewrites something?